# Mongolab Herkoku Deploy Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mlab, nosql

I can't connect my mongolab account to heroku. I have attempted to connect all of the ways in the documentation. It gives me an error and says it cant connect. Any ideas? I am using the below to connect it. Also my app is run in ruby on rails.

mongo @ds055505.mongolab.com:55505/heroku_w42c3vzn -u **my_dbuser_account** -p **my_dbuser_password**

Comment: Specific error messages would be helpful. But the '@' character at the start of the hostname shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that. I'll put an error up. It doesn't leave too much except can't connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

Log in https://mlab.com. And click your database, there will be a button 'add database user'. Add a dbuser. And use this dbuser's name and password to connect your database using mongo shell.